# My app is not showing in search result even after 1 month

Tags: android

It has been 1 month since my calculator app published in play store production. But still it is not in search result. I tried in all hundreds results showing keyword calculator, calculator free etc, but not found my app.
I can see it only by direct hitting the url with my package name.

What to do? Any idea on this, pls share ur app search result experience.

EDIT: Can anyone please help me, I filed up form from google developer support  but they have not responded my query .

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en

Comment: I read this, i saw hundreds of apps are having common term, calculator, calculator free, basic calculator, simple calculator etc...they r visible...what about mine?? Is it it is new??

Comment: I dot know how you published your app. there are a lot of calculators in stored. Double check the app is published correctly and try to search using your package .

Comment: Actually try searching for your name as the author.

Comment: I published properly with step by step, like uploading apk, store listing with all description, images, content rating, made free, checked box export policy etc and clicked published button...it is showing published in dashboard console from last 1 month. I understand lot of calc apps r there...i can get it by package name like com.my package name...but it shd appear in general keyword search... :(

Comment: Hi rohit, i can see my app by searching my name as author... But why general users will search by name ? :( np one knows me

Answer (score 0):

This only happen when user publish in alpha/beta mode . have you published in production mode?

Comment: Yes in production from beginning

Answer (score 0):

Play store search is too simplistic.  I often can not find the apps even when I know that they are there.  The only solution I have is to try renaming it something unique and refine the terms